# Something wrong with my VBO

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to emulate exactly how a game sets up a VBO and draws it to the screen. I've never set one up before and the tutorials all show how to do it with glDrawArrays but I want to use glDrawElements.

I came up with the following:

```
glViewport(0, 0, 765, 553);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, 765, 553, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

xCast(ptr_glActiveTextureARB, ptr_wglGetProcAddress("glActiveTextureARB"));
xCast(ptr_glMultiTexCoord2fARB, ptr_wglGetProcAddress("glMultiTexCoord2fARB"));
xCast(ptr_glGenBuffersARB, ptr_wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffersARB"));
xCast(ptr_glBindBufferARB, ptr_wglGetProcAddress("glBindBufferARB"));
xCast(ptr_glBufferDataARB, ptr_wglGetProcAddress("glBufferDataARB"));

struct PointInfo
{
    float Pos[3];
    float Colour[3];
};

const int NumVerts = 3, NumInds = 3;
std::vector<PointInfo> Vertices;
Vertices.push_back({{0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}, {1, 1, 1}}); ///top left;
Vertices.push_back({{0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, {1, 1, 1}}); ///bottom middle;
Vertices.push_back({{1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}, {1, 1, 1}}); ///top right;

std::vector<std::uint32_t> Indices = {0, 1, 2};

std::uint32_t VBO = 0, IBO = 0;
ptr_glGenBuffersARB(1, &VBO);
ptr_glGenBuffersARB(1, &IBO);

///Put Vertices In.
ptr_glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
ptr_glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(PointInfo) * NumVerts, &Vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
Log(glGetError());

///Put Indices In.
ptr_glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
ptr_glBufferDataARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(int) * NumInds, &Indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
Log(glGetError());
```

I run the above only once at the start of my program. Then in my while loop, I run:

```
glPushMatrix();
glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
Log(glGetError());

ptr_glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
Log(glGetError());
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(PointInfo), (void*) offsetof(PointInfo, Pos));
Log(glGetError());
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(PointInfo), (void*) offsetof(PointInfo, Colour));
Log(glGetError());
ptr_glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
Log(glGetError());
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NumInds, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
Log(glGetError());

glPopMatrix();
SwapBuffers(DC);
Sleep(1);
```

But the only thing that happens is my screen clearing. I never see my triangle at all :S I think it might be my view setup via the glOrtho but I'm not sure. Is there anything wrong with what I did? The glGetError just prints 0.. No errors :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangle coordinates you specified are very small. The triangle occupies only half of a pixel at the top left corner of the screen. Try scaling it by 100.

Also I think you're missing calls to `glEnableClientState` with `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` and `GL_COLOR_ARRAY`.

As a general approach I would suggest to take things one step at a time. Start with immediate mode `glVertex` to make sure you got the coordinates and camera setup right. Then add shaders. Then convert to a position-only VBO with DrawArrays. Then add vertex colors. Then convert to DrawElements. That way you have a better sense of where problems might lie.

You might also be interested in the glload library [here](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html) to get rid of these ptr_ prefixes.

Comment: Ahh :) I used the ptr_ prefixes because it's a reverse engineering plugin. I had no choice because those ptr functions are detoured functions. They monitor calls to the game makes so I can imitate them and see how it works. Downside is that I had to write out every single OpenGL function out by hand and export all of them. Took roughly 3hours.

Thank you for the advice. I like it. I'm going to do exactly what you said from now on.

Answer (score 1):

You should use  `glVertexAttribPointer`. The functions you are using are deprecated. Perhaps you could get this code to work, but if you aren't forced to use such an ancient OpenGL, chances are you'd save yourself a lot of trouble.

Oh also manually loading function pointers is extremely cumbersome. I suggest you looked at libraries such as GLload.

A specialized debugger such as CodeXL or gDebugger can be very helpful in solving issues like that.

---

As for the problems in this code, your triangle is simply too small.

Comment: Heh, I just linked you [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166618/is-there-something-that-can-be-done-about-old-opengl-questions) only to realize that it was you who asked it.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg Yeah, I know, I just couldn't handle myself when I saw that one. Your answer is much better though, and I might just delete mine.

Comment: I like both so +1 for both. Yeah since I'm reversing a game and just seeing how it does things so I can learn from it and do them in my own programs, I ended up practically writing my own debugger which writes all opengl calls to a file. I do use gDebugger though :) Excellent software! Great suggestion too. The calls are really old. Perhaps I should just read a tutorial but it was so much more fun seeing what does what rather than reading pages with no examples. I'll start reading tutorials now :(